# How to upload image using AFNetworking + Sails.js

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, node.js, swift

I have some codes from node.js project, it contains a `post /uploadAvatar` router, and a uploadAvatar function:

```
uploadAvatar: function(req, res) {
   req.file('avatar').upload({
      // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
      maxBytes: 10000000
   },function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         return res.negotiate(err);
      }

      // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
      if (uploadedFiles.length === 0){
         return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
      }

      var avatarFd = uploadedFiles[0].fd;
      var json = {fd: avatarFd};
      console.log(json);
      res.json(200, json);
   });
}
```

Right now I want to using this api to upload image using AFNetworking. Current the swift code like below:

```
func uploadAvatar(avatar: NSData, success: JSONBlock, fail: ErrorBlock) -> Void {
    sessionManager.POST("/uploadAvatar", parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData) in
        formData.appendPartWithFormData(avatar, name: "avatar")
        }, progress: { (_) in

        }, success: { (_, responseObject) in
            let json = self.jsonFromResponseObject(responseObject)
            if json != nil {
                success(json)
            }
        }) { (_, error) in
            if let msgData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as? NSData {
                if let message = String(data: msgData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    print(message)
                }
            }
            fail(error.localizedDescription);

    }
}
```

The error response I get is: "No file was uploaded". It seems the node.js can't find my image data. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try providing some other information of the file, such as `filename`, `mime-type`… Use another overload of `appendPartWithFormData` to provide those info.

Comment: @t4nhpt Thanks. It worked by adding `filename` and `mime-type` to `appendPartWithFormData`.